# Android Power Button Press Event to Start a Background Service When the Phone in Screen lock

Tags: android, android-intent, service, broadcastreceiver

My aim is to start a service when the user press the power button 4 times contineously..
How it is simply possible..
Can anyone please give me some working example codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int i = 0;
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER)
    {
        i++;
        if(i == 4)
        {
            // Do something you want
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Add the above code in your activity. This will do. But still you have to look for the continuous 4 clicks on the power button and reset i to 0.

Comment: It is not clear from the question, but I would assume he wants to start a service whenever the button is pressed and not only with his app in the foreground.

Comment: @afk5min Exactly he does not specified that what he want. the code assumes if the activity is running and the user presses power button 4 times.